# Ember-Data objectAt() to get first result does not work

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm populating two templates with data: the first template has detailed information about the model (called Slider), and the second template has a list of the last 5 sliders.

The problem is that when I use objectAt(0) on the result, the model does not get applied to the template correctly. The other template with the list *does* get populated. What I mean is this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    var sliders = App.Slider.find({ limit: 5 });

    this.controllerFor('indexSlider').set('model', sliders.objectAt(0));
    this.controllerFor('indexSliders').set('model', sliders); // this works fine and loads the data into the template
  }
});
```

That code does not work. However, it does work when I replace the indexSlider model with this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    var sliders = App.Slider.find({ limit: 5 });

    this.controllerFor('indexSlider').set('model', App.Slider.find(52));
    this.controllerFor('indexSliders').set('model', sliders);
  }
});
```

...where 52 is the ID of the first result. This leads me to think that objectAt doesn't really work properly for rendering the model on the template, or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to wait for the `find` to load, before trying to access the first object.  You can use the `didLoad` event:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    var sliders = App.Slider.find({ limit: 5 });
    sliders.one('didLoad', this, function() {
      this.controllerFor('indexSlider').set('model', sliders.objectAt(0));
    });
    this.controllerFor('indexSliders').set('model', sliders);
  }
});
```

Comment: for some reason for this to work you need to call find() with a filter `find({})` otherwise `didLoad` wont fire. ie. if you just call `find()`

Comment: Yes, the reason is discussed at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2632 and https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735